# Spring state machine nested machines running synchronously

Tags: java, spring, state-machine, spring-statemachine

I'm working with the Spring State Machine and am trying to configure some nested functionality.  Essentially, I'm trying to run two processes as individual machines nested within a state.  I have the following code for states and transitions:

```
public enum States {
READY, FORK, JOIN, TASKS, TERMINATE,

T1_INIT, C1_INIT, T1_READY, T1_POLL, T1_PROCESS, T1_STORE, T1_DELAY, C1_CONTINUE, T1_TERMINATE,
T2_INIT, C2_INIT, T2_READY, T2_POLL, T2_PROCESS, T2_STORE, T2_DELAY, C2_CONTINUE, T2_TERMINATE }

public enum Events {INITIALIZE, RUN, STOP, FALLBACK, CONTINUE, FIX, PROC_COMPLETE}
@Override
public void configure(StateMachineStateConfigurer<States, Events> states)
        throws Exception {
    states
            .withStates()
            .initial(States.READY)
            .fork(States.FORK)
            .state(States.TASKS)
            .join(States.JOIN)
            .end(States.TERMINATE)
            .and()
            .withStates()
            .parent(States.TASKS)
            .initial(States.T1_INIT, initT1Action())
            .state(States.T1_READY)
            .state(States.T1_POLL, pollT1Action(), null)
            .state(States.T1_PROCESS, processT1Action(), null)
            .state(States.T1_STORE, storeT1Action(), null)
            .state(States.T1_DELAY)
            .choice(States.C1_CONTINUE)
            .end(States.T1_TERMINATE)
            .and()
            .withStates()
            .parent(States.TASKS)
            .initial(States.T2_INIT, initT2Action())
            .state(States.T2_READY)
            .state(States.T2_POLL, pollT2Action(), null)
            .state(States.T2_PROCESS, processT2Action(), null)
            .state(States.T2_STORE, storeT2Action(), null)
            .state(States.T2_DELAY)
            .choice(States.C2_CONTINUE)
            .end(States.T2_TERMINATE);

}

@Override
public void configure(StateMachineTransitionConfigurer<States, Events> transitions)
        throws Exception {
    transitions
            .withExternal()
            .source(States.READY).target(States.FORK)
            .and()
            .withFork()
            .source(States.FORK).target(States.TASKS)
            .and()
            .withExternal()
            .source(States.T1_INIT).target(States.T1_READY)
            .and()
            .withExternal()
            .source(States.T1_READY).target(States.T1_POLL)
            .and()
            .withExternal()
            .source(States.T1_POLL).target(States.T1_PROCESS).guard(pollT1Guard())
            .and()
            .withExternal()
            .source(States.T1_PROCESS).target(States.T1_STORE).guard(processT1Guard())
            .and()
            .withExternal()
            .source(States.T1_STORE).target(States.T1_DELAY).guard(storeT1Guard())
            .and()
            .withExternal()
            .source(States.T1_DELAY).target(States.C1_CONTINUE)
            .and()
            .withChoice()
            .source(States.C1_CONTINUE)
            .first(States.T1_POLL, continueChoiceT1Guard())
            .last(States.T1_TERMINATE)
            .and()
            .withExternal()
            .source(States.T2_INIT).target(States.T2_READY)
            .and()
            .withExternal()
            .source(States.T2_READY).target(States.T2_POLL)
            .and()
            .withExternal()
            .source(States.T2_POLL).target(States.T2_PROCESS).guard(pollT2Guard())
            .and()
            .withExternal()
            .source(States.T2_PROCESS).target(States.T2_STORE).guard(processT2Guard())
            .and()
            .withExternal()
            .source(States.T2_STORE).target(States.T2_DELAY).guard(storeT2Guard())
            .and()
            .withExternal()
            .source(States.T2_DELAY).target(States.C2_CONTINUE)
            .and()
            .withChoice()
            .source(States.C2_CONTINUE)
            .first(States.T2_POLL, continueChoiceT2Guard())
            .last(States.T2_TERMINATE)
            .and()
            .withJoin()
            .source(States.TASKS).target(States.JOIN)
            .and()
            .withExternal()
            .source(States.JOIN).target(States.TERMINATE);

}
```

I was expecting the machine to fork the two machines identified in the Task state and run them as individual machines.  T1 and T2 actions are set up to have a delay in each state within Task.  T1 is delayed 1 second, and T2 is delayed half a second.

What I find is T1 runs through all of it's states and ends before T2 even starts.  Any thoughts on making them run as they should with a fork/join??

Answer (score 0):

You didn't show full configuration, from you code sample at least `taskExecutor` is missing. For example `tasks` sample doing fork/join is using `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor`. Default executor is `SyncTaskExecutor`. Docs have some notes how it is configured.

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-statemachine/blob/master/spring-statemachine-samples/tasks/src/main/java/demo/tasks/Application.java#L189

One other thing in the code example is that you have zero events defined meaning you would not be able to `drive` a machine. You have defined transition from `READY` to `FORK` without an event, meaning it's a triggerless transition. When you start a state machine, it's then changed into its initial state `READY` and anonymous transition takes it to `FORK`. This starting sequence happens during a start and is outside of an actual executor.

Try to define transition from `READY` to `FORK` with an event, then send that event to machine after it has been started and parallel execution should work(assuming taskExecutor is properly set).

Answer (score -1):

In fact, here's the code for the entire FSM configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableStateMachine
@WithStateMachine
public class FSMFactoryConfig extends EnumStateMachineConfigurerAdapter<States, Events> {

@Autowired
StateMachine<States, Events> stateMachine;

ArrayList<IDataProcessor> dp = new ArrayList<>();

private void createProcessors() {
    dp.add(0, (IDataProcessor) new DataProcessor());
    dp.add(1, (IDataProcessor) new DataProcessor2());
}

@Override
public void configure(StateMachineConfigurationConfigurer<States, Events> config)
        throws Exception {

    createProcessors();

    config
            .withConfiguration()
            .autoStartup(false)
            .taskExecutor(taskExecutor())
            .taskScheduler(new ConcurrentTaskScheduler())
            .listener(new StateMachineEventListener());
}

@Override
public void configure(StateMachineStateConfigurer<States, Events> states)
        throws Exception {
    states
            .withStates()
            .initial(States.READY)
            .fork(States.FORK)
            .state(States.TASKS)
            .join(States.JOIN)
            .end(States.TERMINATE)
            .and()
            .withStates()
            .parent(States.TASKS)
            .initial(States.T1_INIT, initT1Action())
            .state(States.T1_READY)
            .state(States.T1_POLL, pollT1Action(), null)
            .state(States.T1_PROCESS, processT1Action(), null)
            .state(States.T1_STORE, storeT1Action(), null)
            .state(States.T1_DELAY)
            .choice(States.C1_CONTINUE)
            .end(States.T1_TERMINATE)
            .and()
            .withStates()
            .parent(States.TASKS)
            .initial(States.T2_INIT, initT2Action())
            .state(States.T2_READY)
            .state(States.T2_POLL, pollT2Action(), null)
            .state(States.T2_PROCESS, processT2Action(), null)
            .state(States.T2_STORE, storeT2Action(), null)
            .state(States.T2_DELAY)
            .choice(States.C2_CONTINUE)
            .end(States.T2_TERMINATE);

}

@Override
public void configure(StateMachineTransitionConfigurer<States, Events> transitions)
        throws Exception {
    transitions
            .withExternal()
            .source(States.READY).target(States.FORK)
            .and()
            .withFork()
            .source(States.FORK).target(States.TASKS)
            .and()
            .withExternal()
            .source(States.T1_INIT).target(States.T1_READY)
            .and()
            .withExternal()
            .source(States.T1_READY).target(States.T1_POLL)
            .and()
            .withExternal()
            .source(States.T1_POLL).target(States.T1_PROCESS).guard(pollT1Guard())
            .and()
            .withExternal()
            .source(States.T1_PROCESS).target(States.T1_STORE).guard(processT1Guard())
            .and()
            .withExternal()
            .source(States.T1_STORE).target(States.T1_DELAY).guard(storeT1Guard())
            .and()
            .withExternal()
            .source(States.T1_DELAY).target(States.C1_CONTINUE)
            .and()
            .withChoice()
            .source(States.C1_CONTINUE)
            .first(States.T1_POLL, continueChoiceT1Guard())
            .last(States.T1_TERMINATE)
            .and()
            .withExternal()
            .source(States.T2_INIT).target(States.T2_READY)
            .and()
            .withExternal()
            .source(States.T2_READY).target(States.T2_POLL)
            .and()
            .withExternal()
            .source(States.T2_POLL).target(States.T2_PROCESS).guard(pollT2Guard())
            .and()
            .withExternal()
            .source(States.T2_PROCESS).target(States.T2_STORE).guard(processT2Guard())
            .and()
            .withExternal()
            .source(States.T2_STORE).target(States.T2_DELAY).guard(storeT2Guard())
            .and()
            .withExternal()
            .source(States.T2_DELAY).target(States.C2_CONTINUE)
            .and()
            .withChoice()
            .source(States.C2_CONTINUE)
            .first(States.T2_POLL, continueChoiceT2Guard())
            .last(States.T2_TERMINATE)
            .and()
            .withJoin()
            .source(States.TASKS).target(States.JOIN)
            .and()
            .withExternal()
            .source(States.JOIN).target(States.TERMINATE);

}



@Bean
public Guard<States, Events> initChoiceGuard() {
    return new Guard<States, Events>() {

        @Override
        public boolean evaluate(StateContext<States, Events> context) {
            System.out.println("in initChoiceGuard...");
            return true;
        }
    };
}

int i1 = 0;
int i2 = 0;

@Bean
public Guard<States, Events> continueChoiceT1Guard() {

    return new Guard<States, Events>() {
        @Override
        public boolean evaluate(StateContext<States, Events> context) {
            System.out.println("in continueChoiceT1Guard - count: " + i1);
            return (i1++ < 5);
        }
    };
}

@Bean
public Guard<States, Events> continueChoiceT2Guard() {

    return new Guard<States, Events>() {
        @Override
        public boolean evaluate(StateContext<States, Events> context) {
            System.out.println("in continueChoiceT2Guard - count: " + i2);
            return (i2++ < 10);
        }
    };
}

@Bean
public Guard<States, Events> tasksChoiceGuard() {
    return new Guard<States, Events>() {

        @Override
        public boolean evaluate(StateContext<States, Events> context) {
            System.out.println("in tasksChoiceGuard");
            return true;
        }
    };
}

@Bean
public Action<States, Events> initT1Action() {
    return new Action<States, Events>() {
        @Override
        public void execute(StateContext<States, Events> context) {
            System.out.println("in initAction");
            ((IDataProcessor) dp.get(0)).init();
        }
    };
}

@Bean
public Action<States, Events> initT2Action() {
    return new Action<States, Events>() {
        @Override
        public void execute(StateContext<States, Events> context) {
            System.out.println("in initAction");
            ((IDataProcessor) dp.get(1)).init();
        }
    };
}

@Bean
public Action<States, Events> pollT1Action() {
    return new Action<States, Events>() {

        @Override
        public void execute(StateContext<States, Events> context) {
            System.out.println("in pollAction");
            ((IDataProcessor) dp.get(0)).poll();

        }
    };
}

@Bean
public Action<States, Events> pollT2Action() {
    return new Action<States, Events>() {

        @Override
        public void execute(StateContext<States, Events> context) {
            System.out.println("in pollAction");
            ((IDataProcessor) dp.get(1)).poll();

        }
    };
}

@Bean
public Action<States, Events> processT1Action() {
    return new Action<States, Events>() {

        @Override
        public void execute(StateContext<States, Events> context) {
            System.out.println("in pollAction");
            ((IDataProcessor) dp.get(0)).process();

        }
    };
}

@Bean
public Action<States, Events> processT2Action() {
    return new Action<States, Events>() {

        @Override
        public void execute(StateContext<States, Events> context) {
            System.out.println("in pollAction");
            ((IDataProcessor) dp.get(1)).process();

        }
    };
}

@Bean
public Action<States, Events> storeT1Action() {
    return new Action<States, Events>() {

        @Override
        public void execute(StateContext<States, Events> context) {
            System.out.println("in pollAction");
            ((IDataProcessor) dp.get(0)).store();

        }
    };
}

@Bean
public Action<States, Events> storeT2Action() {
    return new Action<States, Events>() {

        @Override
        public void execute(StateContext<States, Events> context) {
            System.out.println("in pollAction");
            ((IDataProcessor) dp.get(1)).store();

        }
    };
}

@Bean
public Action<States, Events> resetT1Action() {
    return new Action<States, Events>() {

        @Override
        public void execute(StateContext<States, Events> context) {
            System.out.println("in pollAction");
            ((IDataProcessor) dp.get(0)).reset();

        }
    };
}

@Bean
public Action<States, Events> resetT2Action() {
    return new Action<States, Events>() {

        @Override
        public void execute(StateContext<States, Events> context) {
            System.out.println("in pollAction");
            ((IDataProcessor) dp.get(1)).reset();

        }
    };
}

@Bean
public Guard<States, Events> pollT1Guard() {
    return new Guard<States, Events>() {
        @Override
        public boolean evaluate(StateContext<States, Events> context) {
            return ((IDataProcessor) dp.get(0)).pollComplete();
        }
    };
}

@Bean
public Guard<States, Events> pollT2Guard() {
    return new Guard<States, Events>() {
        @Override
        public boolean evaluate(StateContext<States, Events> context) {
            return ((IDataProcessor) dp.get(1)).pollComplete();
        }
    };
}

@Bean
public Guard<States, Events> processT1Guard() {
    return new Guard<States, Events>() {
        @Override
        public boolean evaluate(StateContext<States, Events> context) {
            return ((IDataProcessor) dp.get(0)).processComplete();
        }
    };
}

@Bean
public Guard<States, Events> processT2Guard() {
    return new Guard<States, Events>() {
        @Override
        public boolean evaluate(StateContext<States, Events> context) {
            return ((IDataProcessor) dp.get(1)).processComplete();
        }
    };
}

@Bean
public Guard<States, Events> storeT1Guard() {
    return new Guard<States, Events>() {
        @Override
        public boolean evaluate(StateContext<States, Events> context) {
            return ((IDataProcessor) dp.get(0)).storeComplete();
        }
    };
}

@Bean
public Guard<States, Events> storeT2Guard() {
    return new Guard<States, Events>() {
        @Override
        public boolean evaluate(StateContext<States, Events> context) {
            return ((IDataProcessor) dp.get(1)).storeComplete();
        }
    };
}

@Bean
public Action<States, Events> fixAction() {
    return new Action<States, Events>() {

        @Override
        public void execute(StateContext<States, Events> context) {
            System.out.println("in fixAction");
        }
    };
}

@Bean
public StateMachine<States, Events> stateMachine() {
    return stateMachine;
}

@Bean(name = StateMachineSystemConstants.TASK_EXECUTOR_BEAN_NAME)
public TaskExecutor taskExecutor() {
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor te = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    te.setMaxPoolSize(50);
    te.setThreadNamePrefix("LULExecutor-");
    te.setCorePoolSize(25);
    te.initialize();
    return te;
}

//@StatesOnTransition(target = States.AUTOMATIC)
public void automaticFix(ExtendedState extendedState) {

}
```

Comment: Did you check from logging that which threads are doing execution? I'm little puzzled by a fact that you're autowiring StateMachine in a config class building that same autowired instance as I'd expect that to fail. Also using @WithStateMachine with config class is also a bad idea.

Comment: I'm new to Spring, so I may do some silly things.  Thanks for letting me in on better practices.  The actions are fired sequentially.  I use the continueGuard to determine whether I need to do that task again.  I expected task1 and task2 to run simultaneously, but task1 runs for a count of 5, and then task2 runs for a count of 10 after task1 finishes.  Given they are different regions, I expected them to cycle through the tasks simultaneously..  Is this not what I should be expecting??

Comment: I updated my answer. There's a probable cause why parallel execution didn't happen.